# np.stack changes data outcome

Tags: python, numpy

i'm doing earth sience and have 10 data sets for 10 different days representing the velocity. So i have 10 2D arrays and want to stack them to one 3D array with a new time dimension.
My first day before stacked looks like:

```
plt.contourf(day1)
```

[image]

After i stacked the data it looks like:

```
plt.contourf(u_x[0])
```

[image]

I used: `u_x = np.stack((day1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6,day7,day8,day9,day10))`

I don't know why the data is changing, looks like it is in a new order or something. The shape changed from (748, 943) for each single day to (10, 748, 943) for all days, that's what i expected.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try `u_x = np.stack((day1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6,day7,day8,day9,day10)), axis=1)`

Comment: i want to stack it over a new axis.. i want to go from (latitude, longitude) to (time, latitude, longitude)

Comment: Check the `dtypes`.  And look at some individual values.  Sometimes plots don't give enough information.

Comment: @hpaulj: both dtypes are float32. The difference is the class, when i do: 'type(day1)' i get :<class 'numpy.ndarray'> and for 'type(u_x[0])' i get
<class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'>

Comment: @hpaulj but i dont know what that means...

Comment: What are the other `days` - all the base `ndarray` class, or is one or more already a `MaskedArray`?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I suspect one or more of the arrays is already a `MaskedArray`:

```
In [205]: x = np.arange(3); M = np.ma.masked_array(x)

In [206]: x,M
Out[206]: 
(array([0, 1, 2]),
 masked_array(data=[0, 1, 2],
              mask=False,
        fill_value=999999))

In [207]: np.stack((x,M))
Out[207]:
```

masked_array(
data=[[0, 1, 2],
[0, 1, 2]],
mask=False,
fill_value=999999)

If one in the `stack` is masked, then the whole stack is masked.